# Getting Stack Error, Unexplained

Tags: iphone

I have this code

```
-(IBAction) generateFlashNow:(id)sender{

[textField resignFirstResponder];
NSString *string1 = textField.text;
//NSString *string2 = [string1 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"" withString:@","];
NSArray *arrayOfLetters = [string1 componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

NSLog(@"Log Array :%@", arrayOfLetters);

//NSArray *imageArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];

NSLog(@"Log First Letter of array: %@",[arrayOfLetters objectAtIndex:0]);

runLoopTimes = [arrayOfLetters count];
runLoopTimes = (runLoopTimes -1);
NSLog(@"Letters:%d", runLoopTimes);

int timesThroughLoop;

while (runLoopTimes > 0) {
    NSLog(@"loopedy Loop");

    NSString *LetterString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [arrayOfLetters objectAtIndex:indexTimes]];
    timesThroughLoop --;
    NSLog(@"letter String : %@", LetterString);
    indexTimes ++;

    if (runLoopTimes == 0) {
        return; 
    }
}

NSLog(@"done");


}
```

and i get this log report, when I type into the text field 's,a,m'

```
[Session started at 2010-01-15 15:50:30 +1300.]
2010-01-15 15:50:35.398 Flash![39290:207] Log Array :(
s,
a,
m
```

)
    2010-01-15 15:50:35.399 Flash![39290:207] Log First Letter of array: s
    2010-01-15 15:50:35.399 Flash![39290:207] Letters:2
    2010-01-15 15:50:35.400 Flash![39290:207] loopedy Loop
    2010-01-15 15:50:35.400 Flash![39290:207] letter String : s
    2010-01-15 15:50:35.401 Flash![39290:207] loopedy Loop
    2010-01-15 15:50:35.401 Flash![39290:207] letter String : a
    2010-01-15 15:50:35.402 Flash![39290:207] loopedy Loop
    2010-01-15 15:50:35.402 Flash![39290:207] letter String : m
    2010-01-15 15:50:35.404 Flash![39290:207] loopedy Loop
    2010-01-15 15:50:35.405 Flash![39290:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSCFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (3) beyond bounds (3)'
    2010-01-15 15:50:35.406 Flash![39290:207] Stack: (
        29287515,
        2538743049,
        29371451,
        29371290,
        478409,
        74279,
        9945,
        2716761,
        3124130,
        3132867,
        3128079,
        2821683,
        2730012,
        2756789,
        37383889,
        29072256,
        29068360,
        37377933,
        37378130,
        2760707,
        9228,
        9082
    )

and I have no idea what I am doing wrong, so any help is appreciated.

Cheers, Sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never decrement `runLoopTimes` inside the loop. So it will loop indefinitely. And eventually `indexTimes` is off the end of the array.

Comment: Woops, didn't do that, no. 

Cheers Anon.